# Is it possible to extract multiple items from a list in R with map()?

Tags: r, list, dictionary, purrr

With the use of the various `map()` functions from the purrr package, you can pass an integer or a character string to the function and extract the element from a sublist. These work as I'd expect them to:

```
listy <- list(A = list("silence", "cats", X = list(Aa = "dogs", "birds")),
              B = list("silence", "fish-head", Y = list(Bb = "fish-face", "squirrel")))

> str(listy)
List of 2
 $ A:List of 3
  ..$  : chr "silence"
  ..$  : chr "cats"
  ..$ X:List of 2
  .. ..$ Aa: chr "dogs"
  .. ..$   : chr "birds"
 $ B:List of 3
  ..$  : chr "silence"
  ..$  : chr "fish-head"
  ..$ Y:List of 2
  .. ..$ Bb: chr "fish-face"
  .. ..$   : chr "squirrel"

list1 <- listy %>% map(1) %>% str  # returns "silence" from A and B
list2 <- listy %>% map(2) %>% str  # returns "cats" and "fish-head"
list3 <- listy %>% map(c(3, 1)) %>% str # returns "dogs" and "fish-face" from the lists X and Y within the list.
```

My question is, how do I extract more than one element from this list? If I wanted "silence" from A and B, and "cats" and "fish-head" from A and B (in other words, elements 1 and 2 of both A and B), is that possible with `map()`? And if not, what's the best way to do this?

Here's what I would have thought would work:

```
list4 <- listy %>% map(1, 2) %>% str
```

Where 1 refers to the first element from each sub-list, and 2 to the second. But this returns the same as `list1`, above. Using `c(1, 2)` does not work, as it refers to a nested structure (i.e. `[[1]][[2]]`). I've looked through the documentation and a few examples found through Google, but no luck. Any ideas?

Update: I should explain that ideally I'd like to be able to select the elements by name, as in "silence". This doesn't seem to be working too well, however. (I have several large lists where the position of the elements I want changes)

Comment: To "select elements by name," you will probably have to name the list elements. Working with named lists is probably the way to go. Then you can replace the 1:2 in our answers with a vector of element names without any further changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(purrr)
listy %>% map(., function(x) c(x[[1]], x[[2]]))

$A
[1] "silence" "cats"   

$B
[1] "silence"   "fish-head"
```

To get the output in the form of a `data.frame`,

```
listy %>% map_df(., function(x) c(x[[1]], x[[2]]))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
        A         B
    <chr>     <chr>
1 silence   silence
2    cats fish-head
```

Or, as suggested by @Richard Scriven,

```
map(listy, ~ unlist(.[1:2]))
```

Comment: Or even `map(listy, ~ unlist(.[1:2]))`

Comment: Thanks Sumedh and Richard, this answers my question. I would ideally like to avoid the `x[[1]]` notation though, and as I edited in my question, it would be great to select the elements by name (i.e. map(listy, "silence")), as in the purrr vignette. Any ideas on how to do that? If you could add it to your answer, I'd accept it as an answer.

Comment: My mistake, it is possible to select the elements using @Sumedh's answer and strings. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options in base R with `lapply`.

To retain the nested list structure, use

```
lapply(listy, "[", 1:2)
$A
$A[[1]]
[1] "silence"

$A[[2]]
[1] "cats"


$B
$B[[1]]
[1] "silence"

$B[[2]]
[1] "fish-head"
```

To return a single list of vectors use

```
lapply(listy, function(i) unlist(i[1:2]))
$A

"silence"    "cats" 

$B

  "silence" "fish-head"
```

You can wrap the second method in `data.frame` to return a data.frame.

```
data.frame(lapply(listy, function(i) unlist(i[1:2])))
        A         B
1 silence   silence
2    cats fish-head
```